# Cannot create array of structs within another struct in ethereum voting application

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm attempting to create a voting application in Solidity where I want to initialise an array of candidate structs that can be referenced within a larger struct.  However, I consistently get the error message when migrating:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Vote.Candidate memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

```
Candidate[] public candidates;
uint public candidateCount;

function addCandidate(string memory name) public {
    candidates.length += 1;
    Candidate memory newCandidate;
    candidateCount++;
    newCandidate.name = name;
    newCandidate.id = candidateCount;
    newCandidate.voteCount = 0;
    candidates[candidateCount] = newCandidate;
}

struct Candidate  {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint voteCount;
}

constructor () public {
    addCandidate("Cand1");
}
```

This should store the 'Cand1' struct in the candidates array.

Is there something that I'm missing?  Thanks in advance.  I cannot find any information online!

Comment: If I change `candidateCount` to `candidateCount - 1`, your code runs as-is in Remix using Solidity 0.5.2. I couldn't reproduce the error message you reported, nor do I see any such copy happening in the code you shared. Could you share a full contract that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Solidity are held in `storage` instead of `memory`. Pleas reference [this article](https://medium.com/loom-network/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-how-to-initialize-an-array-inside-a-struct-184baf6aa2eb) for a better understanding of the difference between the two. Since storage is dynamic, you cannot directly add an element to an index as that index may not exist in storage. If you wish to add an element to a dynamic storage array, you should use `push()` like so:

```
function addCandidate(string memory name) public {
    Candidate memory newCandidate = Candidate(candidateCount, name, 0);
    candidates.push(newCandidate);
}
```

A secondary option would be to use a mapping as mappings are more favorable than arrays within Solidity due to less complexity and cost. However, with using a mapping you may have to keep track of the length and indices separately dependent upon your specific implementation requirements.